# How to specify --recurse-submodules strategy in SmartGit for git fetch

Tags: git, recursion, git-submodules, smartgit

SmartGit is explicitly using the submodule update strategy `no`. How can I overwrite it to use the strategy `on-demand`?

Executed command by SmartGit:

`git.exe fetch --progress --prune --recurse-submodules=no origin`

I tried to overwrite the fetch command with an alias:

`git config --global alias.fetch 'git fetch --recurse-submodules=on-demand'`

I see no changes in SmartGit's log window.

Comment: SmartGit will fetch necessary submodules on Pull (not Fetch). Why do you want to fetch them already on fetch?

Comment: because a git merge doesn't fetch submodules on demand, but exits with an error that a commit hash in a submodule is not present and aborts the merge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of SmartGit 17, it's not possible to change `--recurse-submodules=` strategy. However, in the **Repository|Settings**, on **Pull** tab, you can configure to **Always fetch new commits, tags and branches from submodule**.

Comment: We don't use git pull in our Git flow. A pull can cause a lot of trouble.